# Save last "copy" from clipboard to file

Tags: command-line, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I am able to copy a massive string of text but unable to paste it anywhere without the program crashing.

So, I wonder: How can I fetch it from the clipboard via CLI and save it to a file instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`xclip` is the command line interface to X selections (clipboard)

```
xclip -o > helloworld.c
```

You may need to modify the command depending on the selection you're using

```
   -selection
          specify  which  X  selection  to use, options are "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" for XA_SECONDARY or
          "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've used this before but I couldn't remember the command for the life of me!

Comment: For images you might need `-t image/png`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a file browser extension for that :) [+info](https://github.com/costales/clipboard-to-file).

Best regards.